# Python Mongoengine Required=True validation rule not working

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

```
class Song(db.Document):
    # defineing varables 
    Id = db.IntField(min_value = 0, unique=True, Required=True)
    songName = db.StringField(unique=True,max_length = 100, Required = True)

    def json(self):
        song_dict = {
                        "Id": self.Id,
                        "songName": self.songName
                      }
        return json.dumps(song_dict)
    
    meta = {
             "indexes": ["Id"],
             "ordering" :["-date_created"]
             }

## Define route to create database and added the data to the database.
@app.route('/audiometa', methods=['POST'])
def create_audiometa():
    #Datetime=datetime.now()
    try:
        _json = request.json
        if _json['audioFileType'] in audiotypeList:
            audioFileType =_json['audioFileType']
            try:
                record=eval(audioFileType)(**_json['audioFileMetadata'])
                record.save() 
                return Response(response = json.dumps({"message": "Record Added Succesfully"}),status=200)
            except Exception as e:
                return Response(response = json.dumps({"Error" : "Error \n %s" % (e)}),status=400)
        else:
             return Response(response = json.dumps({"message": ""}),status=400)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(response = json.dumps({"Error" : "Error \n %s" % (e)}),status=400)
```

I am defining a route to post the JSON file as data to the database. Using mongoengine library with python for database requests.

I have defined all fields as required but while I post JSON from postman it uploads to the database successfully, though several fields are missing.
like,

like,
The right one to required is this only.....

```
{"audioFileType": "Song", "audioFileMetadata": {"Id":"12123232003", 
                                                "songName":"I wanna grow old with you."
                                                 }
  }
```

but it also accepts this where **songName** is missing.....

```
{"audioFileType": "Song", "audioFileMetadata": {"Id":"12123232003"
                                                 }
  }
```

is there anything I missed please let me know...It's my first post on StackOverflow so if I make any mistake please let me know that also....

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a simple typo in your field definition, it is `required=True` (lowercase) instead of `Required=True`.

Additional remark, MongoEngine adds a field `id=ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)` if you don't set an attribute with "id" as name, so in your case you actually have both `id` and `Id` on your instances.